# how to configure extra msm-lsuart on msm8909 gpio

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, qualcomm

We are currently using your MSM8909 processor in Quectel EC20 on the Android Platform.

In this module 2 UART is physically available and accessible.

As per Our requirement, we need 5 serial ports for different hardware interfaces.

we have many GPIO pins are available. It is possible to configure msm-lsuart on these pins.

Currently, we build android 8.1 in MSM8909.

how to generate and access the extra serial port.

Comment: Do you mean to *emulate* UART by bit banging? Forget about it. Even if you able to run some tests and they are pass, it utterly error prone in non-RT OSes. The easiest solution to use SoC with necessary amount of ports.

Comment: I mean BAM Low-Speed Peripheral (BLSP) interface or any other method. my processor 6 BLSP available. 2 available port is already configured with  BLSP1 and BLSP2.